# out of bound check for multidimensional arrays

Tags: c++

I am reading a book on Safe C++. Here, the author mentioned how to avoid out of bound array reading. Here, it is mentioned how we can avoid out of bound array reading for multi dimension arrays. Here author used `operator()` function as shown in following link instead of `operator[]` and gave following explanation.

https://github.com/vladimir-kushnir/SafeCPlusPlus/blob/master/scpp_matrix.hpp

Note here that to access multidimensional array, we either need to use multiple `[]` operators, such as matrix[i][j], or a single `()` operator, such as matrix(i,j).

The first approach can be achieved if we had the `[]` operator return a `T*` pointer to the zeroth element of i-th row. However, this denies us the diagnosis of a column index out of bounds, which defeats the purpose of catching bugs at run-time. We could, of course, create some template class that would include a smart reference to a row, return an instance of using the first operator(`[i]`), and then use the bounds check in the second operator (`[j]`).

My question what does author mean by "**create some template class that would include a smart reference to a row, return an instance of using the first operator(`[i]`), and then use the bounds check in the second operator (`[j]`)."** ? Request to provide sample code how we can implement above logic in C++?

Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: Could you enlighten us with your efforts so far on this

Comment: How can there be efforts so far when the question is "what does this mean"?

Comment: The author means you return an object that contains an embedded reference to the start of the indexed row, and within that object, the size limits so it (the objects) overridden `operator []` can bounds check indexing that dimension similar to how the first dimension was indexed.

Comment: Just use the second method. `[][]` is overrated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The basic idea looks something like this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
class matrix { 
    size_t cols;
    size_t rows;
    std::vector<T> data;

    class row_proxy {  // This class is the part the question really asked about
        size_t row;
        matrix &m;
    public:
        row_proxy(matrix &m, size_t row) : row(row), m(m) {}

        T &operator[](size_t col) {
            if (row >= m.rows || col >= m.cols) // Note: row & col are indices not array count
                throw std::logic_error("Bad index");
            return m.data[row * m.cols + col];
        }
    };

public:

    matrix(size_t cols, size_t rows) : rows(rows), cols(cols), data(rows*cols) {}

    row_proxy operator[](size_t row) { 
        return row_proxy(*this, row);
    }
};

int main() { 
    matrix<int> m(3, 3);

    for (int i=0; i<3; i++)   // fill the matrix with identifiable numbers
        for (int j=0; j<3; j++)
            m[i][j] = i * 100 + j;

    for (int i=0; i<3; i++) { // show the content
        for (int j=0; j<3; j++)
            std::cout << m[i][j] << "\t";
        std::cout << "\n";
    }

    try {                     // test the bounds checking.
        m[4][1] = 21;
    }
    catch(std::logic_error &e) { 
        std::cerr << e.what(); 
    }

    return 0;
}
```

So, when we create a matrix, we save its size in `rows` and `cols`. When we use `operator[]` on the matrix, that doesn't attempt to directly return a reference to an item in the matrix -- rather, it returns an instance of a proxy class that keeps track of the row and the matrix, *and* provides an `operator[]` of its own.

So, when you use `matrix[a][b]`, The first one just saves `a` and `matrix` into a proxy object. Then the `[b]` part gets invoked on that proxy object. That checks that both `a` and `b` are within the bounds we saved for the matrix, and if so returns a reference to the correct object in the vector. Otherwise, it throws an `std::Logic_error` (may not be the best choice -- just the first one that occurred to me).

I should add that there are quite a few variations on this general idea. Just for one example, you could specify the size of the array at compile time, but passing the sizes as template parameters. This can have some advantages -- for example, `matrix<int, 2, 3>` and `matrix<int, 3, 2>` are entirely different types, so you can't accidentally assign one to the other. It can also have some disadvantages (most obviously, you *need* to know the size at compile time or it won't work at all).

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation. Now I got what author means.